# What does tf.squeeze does to the audio and how can I load an mp3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, voice-recognition

I'm using TensorFlow and I would like to be able to load audio and generate a spectrogram from it. I have little knowledge of how audio internally works.
Currently, this is the code I'm using:

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from IPython.display import Audio

data_dir = pathlib.Path('recordings')
sample_file = data_dir/'testA.mp3'
audio = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(str(sample_file))

# remove last dimension
audio_slice = audio[100:]
audio_tensor = tf.squeeze(audio_slice, axis=[-1])
#audio_tensor = audio.to_tensor()
tensor = tf.cast(audio_tensor, tf.float32) / 32768.0

print("Audio Tensor: " + str(tensor))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(tensor.numpy())
plt.show()

# Convert to spectrogram
spectrogram = tfio.audio.spectrogram(tensor, nfft=512, window=512, stride=256)
    
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(tf.math.log(spectrogram).numpy())
plt.show()
```

I have been reading the documentation and in order to create a tensor I need to either use the tf.squeeze method or audio.to_tensor(). I have no clue what the tf.squeeze method does, but when I use it I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 [Op:Squeeze]
```

If I instead use the method audio.to_tensor(), I'm unable to display the created spectrogram on the plt and instead I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (28224, 1, 257) for image data
```